# Woocommerce Special User Roles Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need some ideas to resolve my issues.

Maybe I am too stupid or I am just too blind :D

As Visitor, you can register on my page as an event organizer or as a customer.

1. I just want that the event organizers can generate a product in the front end.
2. he only needs some fields to be filled and the other fields need to have a default / hidden value that he doesn't can alter
3. I want to display the orders that are generated by this event organizer only to him. as admin, I want to see all orders.
4. show the event organizers the order details in front-end but without editing features

I hope you understand my English and can provide me with further information

Or is it a better way to use the backend and disable/hide the functions he doesn't need?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-add-product-frontend/ try with this plugin

Comment: thats not the solution i need, but thanks. i need some information to solve this programmatically

Comment: You can give csv uploading option to your customer for uploading product and define user access rule.

Comment: but why csv? i think its easier to edit it online in the frontend or give the customer the rights to use the backend. in this case i need to rebuild the product edit site properly. how i can define default values for some fields ?